# Next: Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement a logic which will block main pages and redirect to sign in page in case user isn't authorized. Currently when I'm on "/" no matter is user signed in or no i see a white screen and that error message which is in title. A link to the [origin code](https://innocentanyaele.medium.com/protect-pages-from-unauthorized-access-nextjs-firebase-45fd9ee732b4)

Folder struct:

```
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── (auth)
│   │   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   │   ├── setup-profile
│   │   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   │   ├── sign-in
│   │   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   │   └── sign-up
│   │   │       └── page.tsx
│   │   └── (main)
│   │       ├── layout.tsx
│   │       └── page.tsx
```

Root Layout

```
"use client";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isUserValid, setIsUserValid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        setIsUserValid(true);
      } else {
        router.push("/");
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (isUserValid === true) {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={roboto.variable}>
          {children}
          <LogOutModal />
          <UserProfile />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and following instructions in the article https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-to-test-next-js-page-using-userouter-with-jest/654115 solved my issue. Below is the code for your reference. Add it in your test file to mock the next/navigation.

```
jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      prefetch: () => null
    };
  }}));
```